# Radio button and textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am javascript learner and have been trying to do this

two radio buttons but1  but2

two text boxes    box1    box2

What I need to do is 
when but1 is selected, box1 should be editable and box2 should be readonly.
when but2 is selected, box2 should be editable and box1 should be readonly.

On page load both the text boxes should be readonly.

My code is as below

```
<style type="text/css">
    .field-name {
        color:       #444;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size:   0.85em;
        line-height: 2em;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">


    function makeChoice() {
        if (document.getElementById('but1').checked = true) {
            document.getElementById('box2').readonly = true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('but2').checked = true) {
            document.getElementById("box1").readonly = true;
        }

    }


</script>


<html>

<body>
<table>
    <input type="radio" id="but1" name="vals" onclick="makeChoice()">
    <input type="radio" id="but2" name="vals" onclick="makeChoice()">
    <input type="text" id="box1" value="abcde">
    <input type="text" id="box2" value="pqrst">
</table>
</body>

<html>
```

I do not want to disable the textboxes but make them readonly, so that on form submit i will have the textbox values that i can send to the server.

I do not know what mistake im doing here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "readonly" attibute like this:

```
document.getElementById('box2').setAttribute('readonly','readonly')
```

and clear it like thisL

```
document.getElementById('box2').setAttribute('readonly','')
```

Comment: @ entropy: I have used your code and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your IF statements, you are setting a variable, not testing whether it is in one state or another. You need to use this:

```
if (document.getElementById('but1').checked == true) {
```

Note that there are *two* equals signs. This checks whether the two are the same. Basically, one equals *sets*, two equals *compares*. Of course change both IF statements to the two equals signs.

Also, you say that onload both should be readonly. To do this, add

```
readonly="readonly"
```

to the textboxes. And furthermore, you need to turn readonly off on the appropriate textbox when a radio button is clicked.

So, altogether:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .field-name {
        color:       #444;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size:   0.85em;
        line-height: 2em;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeChoice() {
        if (document.getElementById('but1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('box2').setAttribute('readOnly','readonly');
            document.getElementById('box1').removeAttribute('readOnly','');
        } else if (document.getElementById('but2').checked) {
            document.getElementById('box1').setAttribute('readOnly','readonly');
            document.getElementById('box2').removeAttribute('readOnly','');
        }

    }
</script>


<html>

<body>
<table>
    <input type="radio" id="but1" name="vals" onclick="makeChoice()">
    <input type="radio" id="but2" name="vals" onclick="makeChoice()">
    <input type="text" id="box1" value="abcde" readonly="readonly">
    <input type="text" id="box2" value="pqrst" readonly="readonly">
</table>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i still dont know what is going on

Comment: I edited it several times to add some of the better parts from other answers. It all works now, have you tried the latest version? As to what's going on, check out this: http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/604441/Double-vs-Single-Equal-Sign.htm  Maybe that will help

Comment: Can you share what you have working after editing. because im still not able to make it work!

Comment: I have this, tested and working: http://www.dstrout.net/pub/radio.htm I did take the radio buttons and text boxes out of the table tags, since they did not seem to be necessary.

Comment: Thanks David, im using your function now, but only one radio button seems to be working for me, meaning when i choose the second radio button both the fields are editable.

Comment: In that case, I don't know what to suggest. Everything works fine for me. Can anyone else confirm or deny that it works?

Comment: David, can you please test your page again and see if it working right. It is not working for me facing the same above problem.

Comment: only one radio button seems to be working for me, meaning when i choose the second radio button both the fields are editable

Comment: I see it now, only in IE. Could be a bug in Internet Explorer, but I'll try some stuff and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Alright, fixed. The "readonly" had to be changed to "readOnly" (capital O). See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294687/text-input-readonly-attribute-not-recognized-in-ie7

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're using `=` instead of `==` on your conditionals. Also, you always have to set readonly to false on the one of the boxes, or you'll end up with two readonly boxes after two clicks. Try this:

**EDIT** the attribute name is `readOnly`, not `readonly`. Code also edited to manipulate the attribute directly, instead of using `setAttribute`. See working version on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HeUmV/):

```
function makeChoice() {
    document.getElementById('box1').readOnly = document.getElementById('but2').checked
    document.getElementById('box2').readOnly = document.getElementById('but1').checked
}
```

Comment: I used this function of yours but still no luck !

Answer (score 0):

hope, this code would be of any help.

here is my try:

http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/AAAVp/1/

Comment: Im new to jquery how do i include jquery in my code? please advice

Comment: there are couple of ways to include jquery file. One is to link the google Jquery API path. Second way is to download the latest jquery.js from www.jquery.com and save it to your local folder. here is the link for google jquery API. you just need to include the script tag <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You're making a couple of mistakes.
First of all, your css and javascript code must be included into the `<head>` tag, which should be placed soon after `<html>`, before `<body>`.
Secondly your if statements are incorrect: with just one `=` sign you assign a value to a variable, you have to use two (or in this case three) of them to check the variables against a value, like this: `if (something == value)`.
Lastly, you'd better use the functions `setAttribute()` and `removeAttribute()` to modify the values of the readonly attribute.

The complete code would be:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .field-name {
        color:       #444;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size:   0.85em;
        line-height: 2em;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeChoice() {
        if (document.getElementById('but1').checked === true) {
            document.getElementById('box2').setAttribute('readonly','readonly');
            document.getElementById('box1').removeAttribute('readonly','');
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('but2').checked === true) {
            document.getElementById('box1').setAttribute('readonly','readonly');
            document.getElementById('box2').removeAttribute('readonly','');
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <input type="radio" id="but1" name="vals" onclick="makeChoice()">
    <input type="radio" id="but2" name="vals" onclick="makeChoice()">
    <input type="text" id="box1" value="abcde">
    <input type="text" id="box2" value="pqrst">
</table>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply though but it doesnt seem to be working im using ie7 is it a browser issue?

Comment: I just tried on Safari and Firefox and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5uG63/. Unluckily I don't IE available at the moment. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: oncheck of the radio button, one of the textfield should become readonly, this doesnot work...